# Extract the first matching item from a list based on condition (Java/Guava)?

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava

I have a list of the following objects:

```
class ResourcePermissionDTO {
  PermissionType permissionType;
  ... 
}
```

where PermissionType is the following enum:

```
public enum PermissionType {
   DENY, READ_ONLY, READ_WRITE;
}
```

So, the list looks like:

```
List<ResourcePermissionDTO> myResourcePermissions = ...
```

What I want is to return the first ResourcePermissionDTO found in myResourcePermissions with the most restrictive permission. Currently I have the following, but it is a bit messy and I though there might be a better way to do it using Google Guava/functional idioms?

```
private ResourcePermissionDTO returnTheFirstMostRestrictivePermissionFoundIn(final List<ResourcePermissionDTO> resourcePermissionDTOs) {
    if (resourcePermissionDTOs.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }

    final List<ResourcePermissionDTO> resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfDeny = Lists.newArrayList();
    final List<ResourcePermissionDTO> resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfReadOnly = Lists.newArrayList();
    final List<ResourcePermissionDTO> resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfReadWrite = Lists.newArrayList();

    for (final ResourcePermissionDTO resourcePermissionDTO : resourcePermissionDTOs) {
      switch (resourcePermissionDTO.getPermissionType()) {
      case DENY:
        resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfDeny.add(resourcePermissionDTO);
        break;
      case READ_ONLY:
        resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfReadOnly.add(resourcePermissionDTO);
        break;
      case READ_WRITE:
        resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfReadWrite.add(resourcePermissionDTO);
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfDeny.isEmpty()) {
      return resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfDeny.get(0);
    } else if (!resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfReadOnly.isEmpty()) {
      return resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfReadOnly.get(0);
    } else if (!resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfReadWrite.isEmpty()) {
      return resourcePermissionDTOsWithReadWritePermissionOfReadWrite.get(0);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in imperative style it can be simplified as follows:

```
List<ResourcePermissionDTO> permissions = ...;
ResourcePermissionDTO result = null;

for (ResourcePermissionDTO p: permissions) {
    if (result == null || isStronger(p.getPermissionType(), result.getPermissionType())) {
        result = p;
        if (result.getPermissionType() == PermissionType.DENY) break; // (1)
    }
}

return result;
```

If you prefer functional style, you can reproduce exactly the same (though without short-circuit optimization at `(1)`) using `reduce()`. Guava doesn't support `reduce()`, therefore the following example is in Java 8:

```
return permissions.stream().reduce((result, p) -> {
    return isStronger(p.getPermissionType(), result.getPermissionType()) ? p : result;
}).orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you implement the isStronger method though - assign each enum a number (priority 1-4) and do an int comparison? Or something else?

Comment: If constants within `enum` declaration are ordered by strength of thier permissions, you can use built-in `compareTo()` method. Otherwise, you may assign numbers to indicate strength.

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it

1. Make ResourcePermissionDTO implement [`Comparable<ResourcePermissionDTO>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

> ```
>  class ResourcePermissionDTO implements Comparable<ResourcePermissionDTO> {
>       PermissionType permissionType;
>       @Override
>       public int compareTo(ResourcePermissionDTO that) {
>           return this.permissionType.compareTo(that.permissionType);
>       }
>     }
> ```

1. Add all DTO's to a single list

   `List<ResourcePermissionDTO> myResourcePermissions =`
2. Use Guava's [Ordering](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) to get first item from List

   `ResourcePermissionDTO leastRestrictive = Ordering.natural().max(myResourcePermissions);`